# after installing openjdk 16 and android studios on different user git and docker permissions are completly destroyed

Tags: permissions, docker, git

OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04

Yesterday i installed openjdk-16 and android studios on a different user account. Sinds then my docker-rootless doesn't work and if i do git commands its fine but when i do like `git add -p` i get this error message:

```
Can't locate lib.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0/lib.pm: Permission denied at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 3.
```

And if i use `docker-compose up -d` without sudo (what works previously correctly) i get this error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

But if i do `sudo docker-compose up -d` it works correctly.

Does someone know why/and how this happend and how to fix? I tried to fix it for hours but didn't succeed :(

**UPDATE**
Docker is fixed (see my answer how i fixed it. Only Git is still doing anoing things when i reinstalled it.

Comment: Forgot to say, but if i do ```sudo git add -p``` it will work

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: @ChanganAuto i have ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please always edit the questions to add new information, not just comments.

Comment: Oke @ChanganAuto i'm new to forms, i don't do that much :)

Comment: Well then the first thing you need to understand is this ISN'T a forum, this is a Q&A wensite. Comments are intended for clarification, requests, etc., not for extended discussions like in a forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The system was really messed up. so the best solution for me was to reinstall ubuntu. :(

**OLD**
after a few days to find out to fix it, i came with a solution for docker-compose.

I had reinstalled docker, docker-compose completely with curl.

**DOCKER**
for downloading docker i followed the steps at the official docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

**DOCKER-COMPOSE**
I followed the steps on this article https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04

I only had to change the curl link from 1.26.2 to the latest version 1.29.2

after follow that steps i had to do these 2 commands:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

founded on this page: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/Command+%27docker-compose%27+not+found%2C+but+can+be+installed+with%3A